# is element validity object is extendable?

Tags: validation, lightning-web-components

I want to extend `element.validity`, so that can add more custom error type in that.

Tried many ways to **copy** or **deep copy** and **Object.create** `element.validity` but seems like its not possible

```
...
@api customValidity; 

@api
get validity() {
  const element = this.template.querySelector('[data-id=' + this.json.name + ']');
  return Object.assign(this.customValidity, element.validity);
}

set validity(validity) {
  this.customValidity = validity;
}
...
```

Here `this.customValidity` is showing `{}` object which means nothing copying.

So is it possible to customise this? So what i want to add custom validation where our own error type other then these:

> valid, valueMissing, tooShort, tooLong, badInput, patternMismatch,rangeOverflow , rangeUnderflow, stepMismatch, typeMismatch

can be added.

***Why we want to add custom error type other than these*** 
because some of input type(**number**, **textarea**) pattern doesn't support so we can manually handle if we can add extra **error type** with `element.validity` object.

And if in future, customer wants to add other **custom type** so they can use this ***extended object*** to play with.

**so how we can achieve this?**

if it's not possible.. is there other way to achieve this.

Please suggest about the same.